# Why always one post missing

Tags: wp-query, get-posts

In my custom query, every time I query for posts from a particular category using WP_Query() and the category has 10 posts for example, I seem to be missing a post. So querying for 10 posts only returns 9, querying for 11 posts only returns 10 and so on. Does anyone know why I am always missing one post in my query results?

This is the code I am using that is not working. Some of my other code tests have returned the same results.

```
if($carouselOnOff){?>
<div id="carouselContainer">
<h2 id="sponsorsTitle"><?php echo get_cat_name( $carouselCategory ) ?></h2>
<ul id="carousel">
    <?php $showPostsInCategory = new WP_Query(); $showPostsInCategory->query('cat='. $carouselCategory .'&showposts='. $carouselNumber .'');
    if ($showPostsInCategory->have_posts()) : while ($showPostsInCategory->have_posts()) : $showPostsInCategory->the_post();?>
        <li>
            <?php $data = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'key', true ); ?>
            <a href="<?php  if ($data[ 'custom_link' ]) { echo $data[ 'custom_link' ];} else { the_permalink(); } ?>">
                <?php the_post_thumbnail('sponsor', array('title' => "")); ?>
            </a>
        </li>
    <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
</ul><!--end carousel-->
</div><!--end carouselContainer-->
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Where is this happening? Homepage? All pages? Archive page? How about the code you're using to query the posts, can you put that up?

Comment: append on homepage !... did not test it elsewhere

Comment: Try changing `'cat='. $carouselCategory .'&showposts='. $carouselNumber .''` to `'cat='. $carouselCategory .'&posts_per_page='. $carouselNumber .'&offset=0'`.

Comment: I made some edits to your question, pending approval of course. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: OUPS.... i just start from scratch... and then BANG... it append, the output was FINE all the post was there, but after going through jQuery carousel... one is missing !... have to find out why, but in the carousel NOT in the request !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have a filter running on that page that's adding an `offset` parameter to your WP_Query.

There aren't any really easy ways to search for all filters. The plugin [Hikari Hooks](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/hikari-hooks) is the simplest that I've seen. If you install and activate that plugin and view the problem page, you should be able to view any filters on `request` or `pre_get_posts` or other hooks that might be affecting your output. Then its just a matter of tracking down where they're being added and disabling them before your carousel query.

Comment: Note that the plugin Hikari Hooks is no longer maintained and is not compatible with Wordpress in 2021

Comment: Good point, this answer is about 10 years old. I'd recommend [Query Monitor](https://wordpress.org/plugins/query-monitor/) these days for inspecting the actions and filters run on a page request.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a browser caching issue possibly. If you're on a PC try holding down `Ctrl+Alt+F5` to do a hard refresh and clear all caches.

Comment: not a caching..  for sure !... no pc either !

Comment: Are you saying that the 10th won't show at first, or it won't ever show until an eleventh is added? IF you add an 11th post is it still only showing 10 meaning that the would be 11th post still doesn't appear? How many posts do you have set to show per page?

Comment: Eactly... no way to display the #10 post until #11 is creatred, but #11 dont show when created, until #12.. an so on ...

Answer (score 0):

I was having this same issue, inside the query I had a number set to 1, which I then changed to zero, and presto! this is my new code:

```
<?php global $wp_query; $total_pages = $wp_query->max_num_pages; if ( $total_pages > 0 ) { ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having a similar problem. I'm still not sure exactly what was causing it, but I was able to patch it by forcing a large 'posts_per_page' variable in the query and setting the offset to 0.

```
$the_query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'items', 'offset' => '0', 'posts_per_page' => '9999'));
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be status issue. Try with:

```
'post_status' => 'any'
```